# Cassandra update rows by clustered key

Tags: database-design, cassandra, sql-update

I read that, is not possible to update records by clustered key.

```
create table timeseries (
  type text,
  event_time timestamp,
  event blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_type, event_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (event_time ASC);
```

but the event time should be updatable. How can I update time ? Must I delete old row and than insert new one ? Or cassandra provide som other solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, updates and inserts are the same (upserts). So, if you "update" the `event_time`, you'll really create new row because this column is clustering column.

The solution depends on your requirement - maybe you need to rethink data model to get required functionality.  For example, do you really need to update `event_time`?

Can you describe the task that you're trying to solve?